# Invalid token or compile time error for japanese/chinese characters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, encoding, chinese-locale

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string TestApp_ListItem_騾髏魄鮴鯰鰰鴃鶲_b4823038;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
    }
```

As in above code need to create object of type string using some japanese/chinese string characters used same in visual studio 2010 when i compile its giving me build errors like "Invalid token,Unexpected character".

How can i overcome this problem.
[image: Build error]

Comment: try to add Chinese in control panel take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520473/how-to-show-chinese-character-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Probably an issue with VS2010. Mainstream support ended 7/14/2015. Will never get a fix unless maybe you have extended support but hurry up (7/14/2020) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Visual%20Studio%202010%20(all%20editions) . IMHO you should upgrade VS.

Comment: It's not all characters, it's only complaining about two. Are there any special meaning to those characters? Like reserved words? There are certain characters and words we can't use for names. What happens when you remove the two underlined characters?

Answer (score 3):

Possible useful answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837738/is-it-wrong-to-use-special-characters-in-c-sharp-source-code-such-as-%C3%B1) question.

BTW, I cannot reproduce the errors in Visual Studio 2019 Community/Professional (Windows 10 x64 / Winforms App / .NET Framework 4.6) for neither Chinese nor Japanese. All compiles and works fine even if I targeting .NET Framework 2.0.

**Tested with:**

```csharp
public static string TestApp_ListItem_騾髏魄鮴鯰鰰鴃鶲_b4823038;

public static string TestApp_ListItem_どうもありがとうございました_b4823038;
```

Consider to update the Visual Studio and SDK because old MSBuild/Compiler may contain incompartibilities with CJK characters due to old internal [lexical structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure) in [C# Language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm).